# installing tensorflow 1.x to use tensorflow.contrib

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda3

I downloaded anaconda which has a python 3.8 version. and i installed tensorflow with `pip install tensorflow`.

`from tensorflow.contrib import learn` in my code did not work as tensorflow 1.x doesnt work in python 3.8.

I downgraded to python 3.7 by `conda install python==3.7`. and then `pip install tensorflow==1.15`. But it still did not work and errors came up -- regarding python version still being 3.8 inside python.exe.

How can I go about it? Is there an alternate way to install? Please help. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried separate env for needed python version? If not do `conda create -n myenv python=3.7` [Details](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html). Also if you are using conda it is preferable to use [conda install](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/) rather than pip

Comment: @AlexK. i did that now. but i cant open jupyter notebook now. it says jupyter is not recognized

Comment: Add Jupyter to your new venv `conda install -c anaconda jupyter`

Answer (score 2):

You can download tensorflow1.X from https://pypi.org/

For example [tensorflow1.15.0](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/1.15.0/#files). Select the whl file corresponding to your system.

Then use `pip install path/tensorflow-1.15.0-XXXX.whl` or
`conda install path/tensorflow-1.15.0-XXXX.whl` to install.